# Symfony 2.5 Validation Group: One for registration and one for account

Tags: php, validation, symfony

i have an address entity that i want to validate different on the registration than on the "change address" when im logged in.

Here is my Address Entity:

```
 /**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BooksProj\UserBundle\Entity\AddressRepository")
 * @CustomAssert\AddressChange(groups={"AddressChange"})
 */
class Address
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="address")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
 */
private $state;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
 */
private $zipcode;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $country;

// ...
}
```

When a user registers, i don't want the group "AddressChange" to be validated.
When someone changes his address, i want the "Default" and "AddressChange" Groups to be validated.

For that, i have the following now in my AddressFormType:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' =>  'BooksProj\UserBundle\Entity\Address',
            'validation_groups' => array('Default', 'AddressChange'),
        ));
    }else{
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' =>  'BooksProj\UserBundle\Entity\Address',
        ));
    }
}
```

Is this the only way to handle my purpose ? 
Or can i pass the groups, that should be validated in my ChangeAddressFormHandler when calling:

```
if ($this->form->isValid())
        { ....}
```

somehow ?

I think that the solution i got at the moment is not the best. 
Regards.

Comment: I think what you have is okay. However, if you only want an address change validator on existing users, you could also remove the validation groups so the validator is always attached and only validate on existing users/addresses (check for the existence of an id or a createdAt timestamp, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validator` service, just pass validation groups in array in second parameter.

```
 $validator = $this->get('validator');
 $errors = $validator->validate($yourEntity, array('AddressChange', 'Default');

 if (count($errors) > 0) 
 {
     $errorsString = (string) $errors;

     return new Response($errorsString);
 }

 return new Response('Form is valid!);
```

or second way:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new YourForm(), $yourEntity, array('validation_groups'=>'AddressChange'));
```

or third way:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
                    'data_class' =>  'BooksProj\UserBundle\Entity\Address',
                    'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form){
                        $yourEntity = $form->getData();
                        if(  "Your condition" )
                            return array('Default', 'AddressChange');
                        else
                            return array('Default');
                        }
                ));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. I think, i can't use your first two approaches. I have a formType as a service, so i don't call createForm within my controller. THe first approach is to validate an entity, but im having a formType, the entity is filled later when the form is valid. So the third way (as mine) for me is i think the only possible solution now left..